# Path not found when creating text file

Tags: excel, vba, path

I've been through all stackoverflow posts about this and mostly its wrong path, space, wrong date format etc. etc... Nothing to help me.

I have this chunk of code:

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(SaveLocation & "PONUDA.TXT", True)
a.Write (txtstring)
a.Close
```

where second line produces that error.

SaveLocation is filled as string with various things to create folder tree and final form of it is next:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Otpremnice\2022\January\O1-9_BuyerName\
```

I can confirm that folders are created and do exist, so there is no reason for code to not work. Moreover it worked a month ago when I tested and wrote it...

Were there any windows updates that broke excel or I didn't enable some references?

Excel file is stored on desktop, so is folder I create.

Comment: If you paste that path into Windows explorer does it show you the location?

Comment: Yes. Goes straight to that empty folder

Comment: What does `Debug.Print Dir(SaveLocation, vbDirectory)` give you?

Comment: It gives me dot

Comment: OK so it looks like you have at least read access to that folder - do you maybe not have write/delete?  Though that would be odd if it's on your desktop...  Is there already a file with the same name in that folder?  If Yes is it maybe open somewhere?

Comment: Oh.. Now you triggered the devil hahah. Right click on "Otpremnice" folder and its checked on "Read-Only (Only applies to files in folder)"

Everything is on my laptop, so im admin and logged as admin.

Comment: Still no any improvement. Tried to remove read-only check and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry - I'm out of suggestions.  If you can manually create a file in that location then doing the same thing from VBA should be no problem. You could try testing with `fs.FolderExists` or `fs.GetFolder` and see what you get.  Full error messages are always helpful.

Comment: Check this out... I run my script, i get that error and go in debug. Then I use immediate window to check path with FolderExists and GetFolder which gives me error. *After that i edit SaveLocation so that path is not containing last "\" sign, and they give me true and no error. Then i add "\" to the name file "\PONUDA.TXT" *and press F5 and script runs fine... So i thought i solved my problem... But then i initialy in code removed creating "\" in SaveLocation and added it to "\PONUDA.TXT". After that SAME ERROR and same thing with FolderExists. Then reversed * thing and again everything worked